# index and offset have different meaning in Java Regex?

Tags: java, regex

I'm bit confused with Java doc about Matcher in the definition of `start()` and `end()`.

[`Matcher.start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start())

[`Matcher.end()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#end())

Consider the following code:

```
public static void test()
{
    String candidate = "stackoverflow";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("s");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(candidate);
    
    m.find();
    int index = m.start();
    out.println("Index from Match\t"+index);
    
    int offset = m.end();
    out.println("Offset from match\t"+offset);
}
```

The above will return the following result.

> Index from Match  0
>
> Offset from match 1

As I learned every char array or string will start by Index 0 and it's right in the above expression.
But Offset also returns the same character 's' but why it starts with 1?

Comment: "Returns the offset **after** the last character matched"?

Comment: It's not index-offset semantics. Both are indices, one of the start position, the other of one past the end position. Just like in `String.substring`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't start with 1 - it starts with 0. The documentation makes it reasonably clear:

> Returns the offset **after** the last character matched.

(Emphasis mine.)

Basically it's the end of the match in *exclusive* form, which is common in Java. It means you can do something like:

```
String text = candidate.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
```

Note that your "index" and "offset" should really be regarded as "start" and "end" (hence the method names). The terms "index" and "offset" are effectively synonymous in this context; the important point is that `start()` returns the index/offset of the *start* of the match, and `end()` returns the index/offset after the *end* of the match.